# Cleaning website address using php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to clean up website address using php web development language. I know only a method that is str_replace but i can not apply in this case. Because i do not know value which need to replace with blank. Like that

```
str_replace("http://","",$var);
```

I have these types of web address in a Database Table.

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
example.com/
/example.com
/example.com/
//example.com//
www.example.com/
/www.example.com
/www.example.com/
//www.example.com//
http://example.com/xyz/page.php
http://example.com/dir/img/logo.png
http://example.com/xyz/page.php
http://www.example.com/xyz/page.php
example.com/xyz/page.php
example.com/hhfhf/img/logo.png
example.com/xyz/page.php
www.example.com/xyz/page.php
```

And much more similar like above.

I want to clean all web address and final output should be

```
example.com
```

Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parse_url for this: http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url('http://example.com');
$hostName = $parsedUrl['host'];
```

$hostName is what you want

Comment: also not for "example.com/xyz/page.php"

Comment: I think in your case you will need to add a normalization for the urls. Check for the border cases. pseudo code:
    if starts_with(':') -> add('http')
    else if starts_with('/') -> add('http:/')
    ...

Comment: yes i was think to do same. i need to apply same special function like string match etc but you answer really helped me. Thank you